# mysql root has password set but it allows blank password

Tags: mysql

Its a new installation. I ran `mysql_secure_installation` and set a password.

But I can still login with blank password. If I set `-p` it accepts my new password but also accepts blank password.

```
root@newserver:~# mysql -uroot 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MariaDB connection id is 46 Server version: 10.0.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> quit; Bye
```

There is only one root user account.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select * from user\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Host: localhost
                  User: root
              Password: *lasdhjkladhailuhhiouaw
           Select_priv: Y
             Insert_priv: Y
           Update_priv: Y
```

Comment: Probably because socket authentication for user root is still enabled, could you check this?

Comment: I don't see any socket auth in the conf. How do I check it if its not in the conf?

Comment: `SELECT name,status FROM system WHERE type='module';`

Comment: there isn't a system table.

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.system' doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, that was for MySQL. Use `SHOW PLUGINS;` and look for `unix_socket` or check `netstat -a` for a list of all UNIX sockets.